# How to fit basic custom built model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, mnist

I am used to working in PyTorch but now have to learn Tensorflow for my job. I am trying to get up to speed by creating a simple dense network and training it on the MNIST dataset, but I cannot get it to train. My super simple code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# Load mnist data from keras
(train_data, train_label), (test_data, test_label) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path="mnist.npz")
train_label, test_label = to_categorical(train_label), to_categorical(test_label)
train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label = Flatten()(train_data), Flatten()(train_label), Flatten()(test_data), Flatten()(test_label)

# Create generic SGD optimizer (no learning schedule)
optimizer = SGD(learning_rate = 0.01)

# Define function to build and compile model
def build_mnist_model(input_shape, batch_size = 30):
    input_img = Input(shape = input_shape, batch_size = batch_size)

    # Pass through dense layer
    x = Dense(200, activation = 'relu', use_bias = True)(input_img)
    x = Dense(400, activation = 'relu', use_bias = True)(x)
    scores = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', use_bias = True)(x)

    # Create and compile tf model
    mnist_model = Model(input_img, scores)
    mnist_model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')

    return mnist_model

# Build the model
mnist_model = build_mnist_model(train_data[0].shape)

# Train the model
mnist_model.fit(
    x = train_data,
    y = train_label,
    batch_size = 30,
    epochs = 20,
    verbose = 2,
    shuffle = True,
    # steps_per_epoch = 200
)
```

When I run this I get

```
ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument.
```

This does not really make sense to me because my `train_data` and `train_label` are just regular tensors and per the Tensorflow documentation in this case it should default to the number of samples in the dataset divided by the batch size (which would be 200 in my case).

At any rate, I tried specifying `steps_per_epoch = 200` when I call `mnist_model.fit()` but then I get a different error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [60000,10] vs. [30,1]
     [[{{node training_4/SGD/gradients/gradients/loss_5/dense_17_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_grad/mul}}]]
```

I can't seem to discern where a size mismatch would come from. In PyTorch, I am used to manually creating batches (by subindexing my data and label tensors) but in Tensorflow this seems to happen automatically. As such, this leaves me quite confused about what batch has the wrong size, how it got the wrong size, etc. I hope this simple model is way easier than I am making it and I just do not know the Tensorflow tricks yet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did u solve it ?

Comment: I had some other work to do on Friday so I did not solve it. Hopefully I will figure it out this week and post the solution as an answer to this question

Comment: the best answer is simply to use flatten in the model architecture